# Muslim man marrying a Christian or Jewish woman : Necessary conditions required for a valid marriage

Tags: nikah, interfaith-marriage

What is the ruling on the marriage between a Muslim man and a Christian / Jewish woman? I know that this kind of marriage is allowed but what is the complete ruling on this i.e. is a woman being Christian / Jewish enough and sufficient criteria to get married or is there anything else that needs to be taken care of? What if she does not want to change her religion after marriage?